# Pass properties JAXB context in Glassfish

Tags: jaxb, glassfish, moxy

I'm using Glassfish 4.1 for the development of a web service and I have replaced the default JAXB provider with MOXy (2.6.1) - I have added the "-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory=com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory" to the Glassfish VM Options.

The web service is created from JAXB annotated Java classes and I want to pass some properties to the JAXBContext's created by Glassfish (e.g. org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_FACETS).

Comment: Consider rephrasing to pinpont your exact problem. Describe what is exactly that you would like to know. The above post just documents what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have the next web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "AdminService")
@Stateless()
public class AdminService {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     * @param loginRQ
     * @return 
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "login")
    public @WebResult(name="loginRS") LoginRS login( @WebParam(name = "loginRQ") final LoginRQ loginRQ) {
    }
}
```

LoginRS is a class that has for some members bean validation annotations like `@Size(min = 32, max = 32)`. When JAX-WS produces the WSDL, the included schemas (produced by schema generator class) do not contain the corresponding restrictions.
JAXB RI does not support this yet (https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-917) so I have replaced the JAXB RI implementation with MOXy. MOXy has the next property `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_FACETS` that is used to tell JAXBContext to create the XSD restrictions.
I did not find a way to pass this property (with value 'true') to the MOXy JAXBContext created by Glassfish on application start.